# how to write hasnextInt() in Pseudocode

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

I am new to Java and i am required to write a program that will validate user input to integer. However, i will need to write an algorithm to it too. How do we usually write hasNextInt() in pseudo code? 
i have written something like :

```
WHILE (IF INPUT IS NOT INTEGER)
    OUTPUT "Error, enter integer only: "
    (how do you write this?)
END WHILE
n1 := INPUT
```

Is there anyway that i can improve this pseudocode to make it more sensible?

```
//enter code here
while(!read.hasNextInt())    // check if user input is an integer, if it is not integer, run the loop
{
    System.out.print("Error, enter integer only: ");    
    read.next();    // prompt user to enter input again
}
    n1 = read.nextInt();    // get the data from the input and assign into n1
```

Comment: *"(how do you write this?)"* `DISCARD INPUT` perhaps?

Comment: *FYI:* `read.next()` doesn't actually "prompt user to enter input again". It simply retrieves the current input, then ignores it. There is no prompting. The `hasNextInt()` call is what's looking for next input, which is then later retrieved by the `nextInt()` call.

Comment: Yes, i have figured out if i remove the read.next() then i will get an infinite loop there. So read.next() basically means to clear the current input by the user and allow to prompt user input again in hasNextInt()? 

And why would nextInt() takes the value from hasNextInt() but not prompting user to enter again?

Comment: [Prompt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prompt) - *to assist (one acting or reciting) by suggesting or saying the next words of something forgotten or imperfectly learned.* --- In programming, prompting means to display some text, encouraging the user to enter something. `next()` doesn't print anything, so calling `next()` does not "prompt user" for anything. The comment is incorrect, since it's the `print` statement above it that is doing the *prompting*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode comes in many flavors. Therefore, there are several ways to write things as long as your code stays consistent.

Staying consistent to the rest of your pseudocode, `read.next()` could be written as `CONTINUE` or as `IGNORE INPUT`, for example.